# Hoffman - Definition of Blaschke product

Tags: complex-analysis, hardy-spaces

I am self-studying Banach Spaces of Analytic Functions by Hoffman. I have a question regarding the following theorem:

[image]

According to the author, the set $K$ formed as in the theorem is compact. I do not see how. If we consider the $\alpha_n = 1/n$ for each $n \in \mathbb N$ then the Blaschke product makes sense because the $\prod_{n=1}^{\infty} 1/n = 0$. However, the set $K$ formed out is $K=\mathbb N$ which is not compact.

Is the author mistaken or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: The ”Blaschke condition” is $\sum_n (1-|a_n|) < \infty$, in particular it is necessary that $|a_n| \to 1$.

Comment: Also a holomorphic function in the unit disk with zeros at $a_n = 1/n$ would be identically zero, which also demonstrates that your choice $a_n = 1/n$ is *not* valid.

Comment: The author specifies that the we will call a product of the form $z^p \prod [\frac{\overline{\alpha}_n}{\lvert \alpha_n \rvert} \cdot \frac{\alpha_n - z}{1-\overline{\alpha}_n z}]^{p_n}$ a Blaschke product if $p, p_i$ are nonnegative integers and $\alpha_n$ are distinct nonzero numbers in the open unit disc and the product $\prod_{n} \lvert \alpha_n \rvert ^{p_n}$ is convergent. I read infinite product from Ash's Complex Variables and that the author makes the definition that the infinite product converges if the partial product converges.

Comment: Here's Ash's textbook: https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/~r-ash/CV/CV6.pdf . Such a definition wouldn't invalidate the example that I gave, would it?

Comment: A common requirement for infinite products is that there is an index $N$ such that $\prod_{n=N}^\infty a_n$ converges to a *nonzero* limit. That guarantees that an infinite product is zero if and only if one of its factors is zero. That is also what you need for Blaschke products.

Comment: @MartinR Thanks. Makes sense!

Comment: There are several competing definitions for infinite products. I can elaborate in an answer, but only later when I have more time. (Of course, if you don't need an answer anymore you may delete the question, it is up to you.)

Comment: @MartinR I would love to read what you have to say regarding infinite products. You may post your answer anytime you want. I will not delete this question. $\ddot\smile$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Different authors/text books use different definitions for the infinite product.

The source that you quoted, [Complex Variables](https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/%7Er-ash/CV/CV6.pdf) by [Robert B. Ash](https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/%7Er-ash/), defines

> **P1** The infinite product $\prod_{k=1}^\infty z_k$ is convergent if the sequence $(P_n)$ of partial products $P_n = \prod_{k=n}^\infty z_k$ is convergent. In that case the value of the infinite product is defined as $\prod_{k=1}^\infty z_k = \lim_{n \to \infty} P_n$.

The definition in [Wikipedia: Infinite product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_product) is a bit more strict:

> **P2** The infinite product $\prod_{k=1}^\infty z_k$ is convergent if the sequence $(P_n)$ of partial products is convergent *with a non-zero limit.* Again, in that case the value of the infinite product is defined as $\prod_{k=1}^\infty z_k = \lim_{n \to \infty} P_n$.

It is also mentioned in that Wikipedia article that some authors allow finitely many zero factors:

> **P3** The infinite product $\prod_{k=1}^\infty z_k$ is convergent if there is an index $N$ such that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \prod_{k=N}^n z_k$ exists and is not zero. In that case the value of the infinite product is defined as $ \prod_{k=1}^\infty z_k = \prod_{k=1}^{N+1} z_k\cdot \lim_{n \to \infty}  \prod_{k=N}^n z_k$.

- With definition P1, $\prod_{k=1}^\infty z_k$ can be zero without any factor being zero, e.g. $\prod_{k=1}^\infty k^{-1} = 0$. Also $z_k \to 1$ is not a necessary condition for the convergence of the product.
- With definition P2, $\prod_{k=1}^\infty z_k$ is never zero.
- And with definition P3, $\prod_{k=1}^\infty z_k$ is zero if and only if one of the factors $z_k$ is zero (as it is the case with finite products).

Now let us see what happens with Blaschke products if we choose $a_k = 1/k$, $k \ge 2$, as the sequence of zeros. For fixed $z$ with $|z| < 1$ is
$$
 \lim_{k \to \infty}\frac{z-1/k}{1-z/k} = z
$$
so that
$$
 \lim_{n \to \infty} \prod_{k=2}^n \frac{z-1/k}{1-z/k} = 0 \, .
$$
That shows that for all $z$ in the unit disk, the infinite product $\prod_{k=2}^\infty \frac{z-1/k}{1-z/k}$ is convergent in the sense of P1, and the value of the infinite product *is zero.* This is no surprise as there can be no non-constant holomorphic function in the unit disk with zeros at $1/k$ for all integers $k \ge 2$.

$\prod_{k=2}^\infty \frac{z-1/k}{1-z/k}$ is *not convergent* in the sense of P2 or P3.

So to exclude products which are identically zeros, [Blaschke products](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blaschke_product) are defined for sequences $(a_k)$ of non-zero numbers in the unit disk which satisfy the ”Blaschke condition”:
$$ 
 \sum_{k=1}^\infty (1-|a_k|) < \infty \, .
$$
This condition guarantees that for every $z$ in the unit disk, the infinite product
$$
 f(z) = \prod_{k=1}^\infty \frac{|a_k|}{a_k} \frac{a_k-z}{1-\bar a_k z}
$$
has only finite many zero factors, and that the product converges in the sense of P3. One can show that the converges is *uniform* in each disk of radius $r < 1$, so that $f$ is a holomorphic function in the unit disk, with zeros exactly at the $a_k$. (An additional factor $z^p$ can be added for a zero at the origin.)

Also (finally coming back to your question), $|a_k| \to 1$, so that the set $Z = \{ 1/\bar a_k \}$ is *bounded,* and ”$Z$ plus its accumulation points” is compact.